# Cannot find -libmysql or undefinder reference with -mysqllib with mysql library

Tags: c++, mysql, codeblocks, libmysql

Cannot find `-libmysql` or undefinder reference with `-mysqllib`

Hi I have a problem with a regular connection to the database using the code blocks. `If Include -libmysql -Cannot find`, and `if -mysqllib - undefinder reference`. I also added a folder lib and include in their places, please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "mysql.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  MYSQL mysql;
  mysql_init(&mysql);
  if( mysql_real_connect(&mysql,//example//))
    cout<<"good job";
  else cout<<"bad job";
  return 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are giving incorrect location of the libraries. Please check whether the folder indeed contains the library.